# The forecolor of textbox is reset when I change its backcolor, vice versa (with PostBack)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I have one main textbox with multiline textmode, and another two textboxes with color textmode, one is to change the text-color and the other one to change the background-color of the main textbox.

The problem is that if I change the background color after changing the text color, the text color will be overridden by black color (I guess this is the default color), or if I change the text color after changing the background color, the background color will be overridden by white color (the default color I guess).

I know the textbox value is posted with PostBack request, but I thought ViewState should store the control information for textbox. It still does not if I enable ViewState for the main textbox explicitly.

Somehow I can fix this problem. But, **why does it behave like this?**

**UPDATE**

I have checked this resource: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/viewstate-for-textbox-in-Asp-Net/

When I use radiobuttons, it works. If I use the textbox as the color-picker, then it does not work.

Is this a bug of textbox when used with TextMode set to Color??

Here is the main textbox:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Editor"
        TextMode="MultiLine"
        Columns="50" Rows="10"
        EnableViewState="true"
        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here are the two:

```
    <div class="text-muted">Color Options:</div>
    Text-color:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_TextColor" 
        AutoPostBack="true" TextMode="Color"
        Text="#000000" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt_TextColor_TextChanged">
    </asp:TextBox>

    Background-color:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BackColor"
        TextMode="Color" AutoPostBack="true"
        Text="#FFFFFF" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txt_BackColor_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the related part in the CodeBehind file, whenever a color is chosen the colors of the main textbox should be updated accordingly:

```
    protected void txt_TextColor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_Editor.ForeColor = Color.FromName(txt_TextColor.Text);
    }

    protected void txt_BackColor_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_Editor.BackColor = Color.FromName(txt_BackColor.Text);
    }
```

Comment: It should work, this example is exactly doing that and works: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/viewstate-for-textbox-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I have checked that. Not exactly, if I keep changing ONLY text-color (or background-color) it is working. However, if I change text-color then backcolor, the text-color is reset or vice versa.

Comment: the example is changing both, back color and fore color, don't see the difference, maybe I'mtoo tired :D

Comment: @Gusman you are right, it is the same, and it worked when I use radiobuttons, but it does not work with textbox (textmode=color). I am 100% sure it is the same code.

Comment: if you remove the textmode=color and insert plain text it works?

Comment: @Gusman still the same issue, interesting.

Comment: can you check if may be even when only you change one textbox both TextChanged's are being executed? Also, you aren't changing the fore/back color of the textbox anywhere else, right?

Comment: no I am not changing anywhere else. and TextChaged is executed properly (one each time),  if you want you can try the some code and see how it works in your VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, the problem has nothing to do with textboxes nor ViewStates, its the Color.FromName, if you use instead ColorTranslator.FromHtml it works perfectly, so I suppose the color returned from Color.FromName is really invalid.

Really an strange bug.

**EDIT:** Ok, so I checked the resulting colors and it's not really a bug, FromName must be used only on named colors "red", "blue", etc, if you use it this way it creates a color which has these properties (values are examples) "{Name=#6bea55, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}", as you can see the name has a  prepended # and the RGB values are all zeros because it can't parse it, but if you use the translator then it creates a color like this "{Name=ff6bea55, ARGB=(255, 107, 234, 85)}", so what's happening under the hood is that HTML renderer is using the Name property to fill the value of the style property but the ViewState is storing the ARGB values, when you do a postback it restores those ARGB values and thus the color is lost.

Comment: very interesting that it resets the other one :)

Comment: np, I was curious about why that happened :)

Comment: may I ask you how were you able to view this: Name=#6bea55, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Just paused the debugger, put the cursor over the variable and it will show you those values (at least in VS2013)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to capture the color in a hidden field or viewstate and check it after postback.

Comment: my main question is actually: why does it behave like this?